# ValueError: the greenlet library is required to use this function

Tags: python, wget, valueerror

***Describe the problem***

> ValueError: the greenlet library is required to use this function.

***To Reproduce***

I tried this command. But still have `ValueError`.

```bash
pip install green let
pip install gevent
git clone https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet.git
```

***Expected behavior***

[image: result]

***Screenshots***

[image: ValueError]

***Environment Description***

```
OS: macOS Big Sur 11.5.2
Python version: 2.7.16
Current Shell: zsh
```

I have no idea. Does anyone know what is the problem here?

I really hope to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just observed this when running pytest against an otherwise working service using sqlalchemy.  I hadn't expected to need to install anything futher, so searched to see if I was doing something wrong, and found your question.

I hope you solved it, but for anyone coming next:

`pip install greenlet` worked for me.

note that you have reported attempting `pip install green let` with a space!

```
- pip install green let
+ pip install greenlet
```

This appears to be dependant on using the asynchronous parts of sqlalchemy, and on the sqlalchemy version:
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/6136